# How can I filter data on chart in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, chart.js, fusioncharts

I am working on an angularjs project. I have to use chartjs or fusionchart for drawing charts. I use database to build chart. I want to filter data by client side. For example, user can be filter data by clicking on legend item or user can be filter data by dragging mouse on the graph. How can I do that? Also, I want to use range slider for filtering data on chart.

Comment: Did you see filter API of angularjs ? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Comment: Of course, but I am looking for user friendly things. I have to do filtering on chart. If I use angularjs filter I have to use textbox or something like that

Comment: No, you don't must used angular filter in html. You can use as a service ($filter('filter')(...)). In this way you can filter your data when you want (on a button, on watch events, ...)

Comment: Can you give me example or where can I find similar things ?

Comment: Another issue is every time when filter used do I reload the chart?